# How to check if a php array value is in js array?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

First of all I get all the `values` from a `php array`:

```
<?php
  $user_id = get_current_user_id();
  $userPostsInternal = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post_internal', TRUE );
  $userPostsExternal = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post_external', TRUE )
?>
```

I then get those `arrays` and convert them in a `JS array`

```
var savedInternal = "<?php echo $userPostsInternal; ?>";
var savedExternal = "<?php echo $userPostsExternal; ?>";

savedInternal = savedInternal.split(',');
savedExternal = savedExternal.split(',');
```

I then need to check if current `id value` is in the `js array` and proceed accordingly:

```
if($.inArray(this.id, savedInternal) !== -1) {
    console.log("yes");               
} else {
    console.log("no");  
}
```

This is happening on a mouse over an element, if I place the following the `id` is correct, so it isn't about `this.id`

```
console.log(this.id);
```

I get `128545` and it is correct.

Full code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'mouseover', function(e) {

  <?php
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $userPostsInternal = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post_internal', TRUE );
    $userPostsExternal = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post_external', TRUE )
  ?>

  var savedInternal = "<?php echo $userPostsInternal; ?>";
  var savedExternal = "<?php echo $userPostsExternal; ?>";

  savedInternal = savedInternal.split(',');
  savedExternal = savedExternal.split(',');

  $("#timeSearch").removeClass("fadeIn").addClass("fadeOut");
  $(".infoBox").removeClass("fadeOut").addClass("fadeIn");
  if(this.currSite == "curr" ) {
    var linkGo = this.linkToPost;
    var whatSite = this.currSite;
    if($.inArray(this.id, savedInternal) !== -1) {
      var contentString = '<div class="row infoBox"><div class="col"><p>' + this.site + '</p><hr><h5>'+this.title+'</h5><hr><p><button data-whatSite="'+whatSite+'" data-id="'+this.id+'" type="button" class="btn-site btn btn btn-outline-dark btn-block">Già nella box</button></p><hr><a class="d-block margin-top-20 btn btn-outline-dark btn-block" href="'+linkGo+'">Vedi contenuto</a></div></div>';                  
    } else {
      var contentString = '<div class="row infoBox"><div class="col"><p>' + this.site + '</p><hr><h5>'+this.title+'</h5><hr><p><button data-whatSite="'+whatSite+'" data-id="'+this.id+'" type="button" class="btn-site btn btn btn-dark btn-block">Salva nella box</button></p><hr><a class="d-block margin-top-20 btn btn-outline-dark btn-block" href="'+linkGo+'">Vedi contenuto</a></div></div>';                  
    }
  } else { 
    var linkGo = linkExternal+this.linkToPost;
    var whatSite = this.currSite;
    if($.inArray(this.id, savedExternal) !== -1) {
      var contentString = '<div class="row infoBox"><div class="col"><p>' + this.site + '</p><hr><h5>'+this.title+'</h5><hr><p><button data-whatSite="'+whatSite+'" data-id="'+this.id+'" type="button" class="btn-site btn btn btn-outline-dark btn-block">Già nella box</button></p><hr><a class="d-block margin-top-20 btn btn-outline-dark btn-block" href="'+linkGo+'">Vedi contenuto</a></div></div>';                  
    } else {
      var contentString = '<div class="row infoBox"><div class="col"><p>' + this.site + '</p><hr><h5>'+this.title+'</h5><hr><p><button data-whatSite="'+whatSite+'" data-id="'+this.id+'" type="button" class="btn-site btn btn btn-dark btn-block">Salva nella box</button></p><hr><a class="d-block margin-top-20 btn btn-outline-dark btn-block" href="'+linkGo+'">Vedi contenuto</a></div></div>';                  
    }
  }
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: contentString});
  infoWindow.setPosition(this.getCenter());
  infoWindow.open(map);
  btnBoxSave(infoWindow, whatSite);
});
```

Comment: `$.inArray` uses strict comparison, make sure `this.id` is the same type as the values in the arrays.

Comment: @Titus looks like I cannot get access to the js array on mouse hover in gmap as if I do                   `console.log(savedInternal);` I get nothing yet if I place the whole array bit before the hover states in gmaps, I get the correct values

Comment: $userPostsInternal and $userPostsExternal are php arrays ?

Comment: Try: `$.inArray(this.id.toString(), savedInternal)`, do the same for the other check.

Comment: @FrançoisHuppé yes indeed

Comment: Would help to see what array looks like. Any whitepace in the split elements? Are you comparing number to strings?

Comment: Maybe not relevant to your problem, but why not using json_encode to pass the arrays to js, instead of the .split() ?

Comment: @Titus yes indeed that was it, worked. Would you be able to place that into an answer with a bit of an explanation too for future users and I'll accept it? Thanks a lot

Comment: @FrançoisHuppé actually that is a good idea too, would you be able to place that into an answer in combo with the solution from Titus and a bit of an explanation? Just to have a v2 solution. Thanks a lot. By the way no white space was there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$.inArray(...)`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) uses strict comparison.
From the code that you've posted it seems that the arrays contain strings (they were created using `.split(...)` which returns an array of strings) and the value you're checking to see if it is in the arrays (`this.id`) is a number.

To fix that, use:

`$.inArray(this.id.toString(), savedInternal)` and `$.inArray(this.id.toString(), savedExternal)`

Comment: Brilliant hanks a lot, makes total sense